# Search Refinement Panel

Tags: people-search, refinement-panel, crawled-property

How can I get the preferred name of the "People:Manager"-crawled property in the search refinement panel instead of domain\Accountname?

I mapped a mananaged property to this crawled property but only get domain\accountname?

Can this be done using xslt?

[Update: My Solution]
My solution was to build a timerjob which looks in every userprofile and writes the displayname of the manager in another property. You can use this property on the refinement panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steffen,

you could do the following: do a webservice call to the search service, query each domain/username and retrieve it's displayname. Replace the refiner display values with the returned displaynames.

But I do think that the displayname should be indexed, too. you might investigate it a bit.

Comment: I don't know much about xsl. Do you have some snippets?

Comment: sorry, i don't have any snippets ready for you. But there are a lot of resources where you can find how to modify the xslt and how to include javascript in it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed is not the perfect solution. The reason being, the function calls on the filter click event are async calls and the next page generated after the filter click doesn't run the embedded code. So the next page you will have the same issue. If you click All to go back to the main page, you will see the same problem. You need to either refresh the page after each filter call or handle the async return with Promise function. But, I don't think the inbuilt SharePoint function returns a promise to use