# Refinement Panel Not Showing UserName

Tags: refinement-panel

I am adding a category in refinment panel which maps to a managed property of type People Group. It works fine except it displays login name of the user instead of display name. I need to display name like "Alex Wong" not like "domainname\loginname".

In the refinement panel schema I am using type as "ManagedPropertyFilterGenerator" and using managed property name as "Mapped Property".

Please let me know if you have any idea about how can I display username here.

I checked category name 'Author' in OOB webpart but there 'Author' column type is single line of text not people and group.

Comment: Can you tell us when you log in to SharePoint, and at the top-right corner you see the UserName logged in... Is that a display name or "domainname\loginname"?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to modify the people refinement panel you can do it this way: [Search Refinement Panel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49274/search-refinement-panel)

If it's for a list, you can solve it almost the same way. You could do it with a hidden field in the list.